# how to permanently save tables in sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to create tables in sqlite3. After inserting 2-3 rows of data, and try to access it after closing the current session, my records are no longer there. Please anybody help me, how to save and retrieve the data’s in sqlite3.

Comment: Please show us what you have already done to try and complete this.

Comment: that doesn't sound right.  you will need to show what you did as it sounds like you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Some debugging steps:

1. Check that the disk file is created when you open the sqlite database.  ( Perhaps your app does not have write permission to the location you have specified for the database file? )
2. Check that the tables are created when execute CREATE TABLE.  ( The easiest way to do this is the .SCHEMA command in the command line interface. )  Perhaps there is an error in your SQL code?
3. Check that the data is written to the tables BEFORE you close the session.  ( Again use the command line interface )   Perhaps there is an error in your SQL code?

General questions:

Have you checked the error return from every call to the SQLITE engine?

Have you run your app under a debugger to check that the copde you wrote is actually executing?